# What is the fault in the Image?

Tags: lateral-thinking, geography

[image][Identify the fault in the picture?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am09h.jpg)

Read the Text.

Look at the picture.

Identify.

You might get it.

Comment: The fault in the picture is that it doesn't have a fault! buahahahahah

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Furnace Creek Fault

Reasoning:

> The question is a pun - we're looking for an earthquake fault, not a fault in the sense of 'defect' or 'problem'. 
>  If you reverse image search in Google, you find [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IM23oFbbZ_0/U0JisOvEgeI/AAAAAAAASZA/yZ8uKkI2O00/s1600/P1030945+Furnace+Creek+Fault+Zone.jpg)
>  Which has the tagline Furnace Creek Fault
>  (Also the [blog](http://geotripper1.rssing.com/chan-6045487/all_p14.html) linking it is pretty interesting)

Comment: You got it Right.

Comment: Yep -- a straight GIS for this.

Comment: What does Furnace Creek Fault mean?

Comment: @Xandawesome the term fault line is used to describe earthquake causes. Furnace Creek Fault is name of a fault. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_(geology)

Comment: Oh, I get it, it's a pun. The question suggests 'fault' as in 'defect' but it's actually a fault as in an earthquake fault.

Answer (score 2):

> It's the Furnace Creek fault system -- which parallels the San Andreas one but isn't the same.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because

> the water is missing?
>  I am not sure, but the soil looks like the soil on a river bottom.

Comment: Upvoted because you answered after looking at the accepted answer.